# PHP Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue if using sleep(20) function

Tags: php

I built a bookmarklet that inject JS in a web page and I'm calling via ajax a php file. The script works well when I use a for-loop without sleep, but a as soon I use sleep i get a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. 
Why is that?

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    // do something
    sleep(20); //throw error, why?
}
```

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: You're basically sleep for 100 seconds, maybe you're just reaching `max_execution_time` limit (30 seconds by default)